# Calculation of mean average precision for CNN object detection in python

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, object-detection, precision-recall

I am new to python and CNN.
I trained an object  detection classifier for card images using Tensorflow and then tested it on multiple images (1000 images).

I have got following results for example.

```
**Detection scores and class for Image 1>  Ace: 99%  Jack: 91%  Ten: 75%
Detection scores and class for Image 2>  Ace: 69%  Jack: 91%  Queen : 75%
Detection scores and class for Image 3>  Nine: 99%  King: 92% Queen : 68%
.
.
.
Detection scores and class for Image 1000>  Nine: 95% King: 91%Queen : 68%**
```

How can i calculate the mean average precision in python and how would i incorporate multiple test images. I already calculated scores for these multiple images by passing them one after another but how do i calculate mean average precision for all.

I need to plot the results.

My code for performing object-detection is:

**

```
image = cv2.imread(F_filename)
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #np.float32(image)
image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_rgb, axis=0)

# Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
[detection_boxes,
 detection_scores,
 detection_classes,
 num_detections],
 feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})
 


# Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(f,
image, 
np.squeeze(boxes),
np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
np.squeeze(scores),
category_index,
use_normalized_coordinates=True,     
line_thickness=8,
min_score_thresh=0.60)
**
```

Comment: Could you provide some of the code, please? What framework are you using?

Comment: Tensorflow. 

**image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
    image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_rgb, axis=0)
    
    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes,
     detection_scores,
     detection_classes,
     num_detections],
     feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})**

Comment: It's better to add your explanation to your question, not in a comment. Also helps with the layout.